# Update an SQL table based on another table, the result needs to mark the rows missing

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am tracking employees and want to have a running master list. I have an SAP export that gives me the list of current employees. Every month I want to update my master table. Essentially I'd like to combine my master table with another table (this table will only have the results from the most recent SAP export) if the master contains rows that are not already marked as expired, but the row is not present in the SAP export I want it to mark that row as expired. If the row from the SAP export is not currently in the master list I want it to add it.

Table - Master List

```
Name | Department | Position | Active
Test1   Dept2      Role1      True
Test2   Dept2      Role2      False
Test3   Dept2      Role1      True
```

Table - SAP Export

```
Name | Department | Position | Active
Test1   Dept2      Role1      True
Test4   Dept2      Role2      True
```

Table - Result (Master Table)

```
Name | Department | Position | Active
Test1   Dept2      Role1      True
Test2   Dept2      Role2      False
Test3   Dept2      Role1      False
Test4   Dept2      Role1      True
```

Can anyone point me in the direction of a similar request?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide the source and target table schema and a few lines of sample rows.

Comment: added some example tables/results

Answer (score 1):

For general approach, you can use LEFT and INNER Joins to detect matching and missing records if you join on Primary Key.

If you LEFT JOIN the tables together, and look for NULL values in the right hand table, it will tell you which rows don't exist in the LEFT table.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following. I am assuming the column `Name` is your primary key.

- Insert the SAP export to a separate table (this can also be a temporary table). Lets call it tempTable. Since you haven't specified how the export file looks like (whether it's CSV/Excel etc.. I can't go into the details of how you import this table to the SQL database)
- Update the status of records in the Master table depending on the records in tempTable

  UPDATE MasterList Set [Active]='false' WHERE [Name] NOT IN (SELECT [Name] From tempTable)
- Insert the new rows that's not present in `MasterList`

  INSERT INTO MasterList ([Name],[Department],[Position],[Active]) Values (SELECT * FROM tempTable WHERE tempTable.Name <> MasterList.Name)
- Truncate the `tempTable`

Comment: I'm getting some errors on the insert part (pardon the formatting, not sure how to format these comments)  

INSERT INTO [-].[dbo].[tblEmployee] Values(SELECT * FROM [-].[dbo].[tblS07HeadCount] WHERE [-].[dbo].[tblS07HeadCount].Name <> [-].[dbo].[tblEmployee].Name)

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: Try using named columns instead of * in the `SELECT` query. Also try using named columns in the `INSERT` statement like I have demonstrated.

Answer (score 0):

The following statement should be roughly what you want (assuming you have sap table is in the db already).

Updating expired entries

```
update master_table set is_expired = TRUE where id in (select id from master_table left join sap_table on id where master_table.is_expired = FALSE and sap_table.id IS NULL);
```

Explanation: left join master_table and sap_table on id, if id is null on sap table column of the joined table, then sent the entry in master table to expired.

Inserting New entries

```
insert into master_table select (columns you want to insert) from sap_table left join master_table as t2 on id where t2.id IS NULL;
```

Explaination: left join sap_table and master_table on id, if id is NULL, insert row from sap table into master table.

Answer (score 0):

That seems to lend itself to a `MERGE`:

```
DECLARE @SummaryOfChanges TABLE(Change VARCHAR(20));

MERGE INTO MasterList AS target
USING (SELECT name, department, position, active FROM SAPExport) AS source
  ON (target.name = source.name AND target.department = source.department AND target.position = source.position)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (name, department, position, active)
  VALUES (source.name, source.department, source.position, source.active)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
  UPDATE SET active = 0
OUTPUT $action INTO @SummaryOfChanges
;
```

See it in action: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/63af9/2)

Please comment if and as adjustment / further detail is required.